# How to run crontab in same shell environment every time

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron

I need to schedule a shell script (health.sh) which exports a variable, say export STATUS="SUCCESS" and updates its value later in the script to SUCCESS or FAIL based on some condition.

Using crontab to schedule the script as

```
* * * * * . ./health.sh
```

In every execution of script, i need to access value of STATUS variable set in last execution of script. The value of STATUS is always shown as empty in each execution and last set value is not retained. Need a way to access last set value.

Comment: Write stuff you want to keep in files.

Comment: Avoid relative pathes as `./health.sh` in crontabs. Use absolute pathes instead as `/home/some_user/some_directory/health.sh`.